# Plot the region covered by a map?

Tags: plotting, regions

Suppose we consider two dimensional cartesian coordinates `x,y` and pick a parametrization

```
x = r Cos[phi];
y = r Sin[phi];
```

I would like to plot the region in `x,y`-plane that is covered by the range `0<r<Infinity` and `0<phi<PI/3` in the new variables. Does mathematica have a function that does this?

The plot should look something like
[image]

**EDIT:**

I believe there is a problem in the solution of the current [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/186992/5517) with the plot function for a hyperbolic case:

```
prs = {ParametricRegion[{r Sinh[phi], r Cosh[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, -Infinity, Infinity}}],
       ParametricRegion[{r Cosh[phi], r Sinh[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, 0, Infinity}}], 
       ParametricRegion[{-r Cosh[phi], r Sinh[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, 0, Infinity}}]};
```

I believe the three regions should be exactly touching each other along the adjacent straight lines, while the plot does not seem to reflect that:

```
Show[MapIndexed[RegionPlot[#, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &, prs], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: does `pr = ParametricRegion[{r Cos[phi],  r Sin[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity} , {phi, 0, Pi/3}}];
Region[pr]` give what  you need?

Comment: @kglr looks close, but it would be nice if it had axes with numbers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2:**

If you examine the `prs`,

```
 prs
```

> {ParametricRegion[{{r Sinh[phi], Cosh[phi] r}, r >= 0}, {r, phi}],
>        ParametricRegion[{{Cosh[phi] r, r Sinh[phi]}, r >= 0 && phi >= 0}, {r, phi}],
>        ParametricRegion[{{-Cosh[phi] r, r Sinh[phi]}, r >= 0 && phi >= 0}, {r, phi}]}

it doesn't contain any information on plot region bounds. Intersecting each element of `prs` with `RegionUnion[prs]` eliminates the issue:

```
Show[MapIndexed[RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[#, RegionUnion @@ prs], 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &, prs], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can `RegionPlot` the intersection of each element of `prs` with, say, `Rectangle[{-50, 0}, {50, 50}]`:

```
Show[MapIndexed[RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[#, Rectangle[{-50, 0}, {50, 50}]], 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &, prs], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

You can use [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html):

```
pr = ParametricRegion[{r Cos[phi], r Sin[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity} , {phi, 0, Pi/3}}];
RegionPlot[pr]
```

[image]

**Update:** *Is there a way to glue several parametric regions together?*

```
prs = ParametricRegion[{r Cos[phi], r Sin[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, ##}}] & @@@ 
  {{0, Pi/3}, {2 Pi/3, Pi}};

Show[MapIndexed[RegionPlot[#, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]] &,  prs], 
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to glue several parametric regions together? Like for `{phi, 0, Pi/3}` and `{phi,2Pi/3, Pi}` for instance?

Comment: @Kagaratsch, please see the update.

Comment: I believe there is a problem with the plot function for a hyperbolic case: `prs = {ParametricRegion[{r Sinh[phi], 
     r Cosh[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, -Infinity, Infinity}}], 
   ParametricRegion[{r Cosh[phi], 
     r Sinh[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, 0, Infinity}}], 
   ParametricRegion[{-r Cosh[phi], 
     r Sinh[phi]}, {{r, 0, Infinity}, {phi, 0, Infinity}}]};` I believe the three regions should be exactly touching each other along the adjacent straight lines, while the plot does not seem to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed before that, as mentioned by OP, region functions do seem to have numerical problems which causes them not to render regions, other than simple ones, correctly. But there is also `ParametricPlot` which seems to work:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  {r Sinh[phi], r Cosh[phi]},
  {r, 0, 10^5}, {phi, -10^3, 10^3},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 1],
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 2}}
  ],
 ParametricPlot[
  {r Cosh[phi], r Sinh[phi]},
  {r, 0, 10^5}, {phi, -10^3, 10^3},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 2],
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 2}}
  ],
 ParametricPlot[
  {-r Cosh[phi], r Sinh[phi]},
  {r, 0, 10^5}, {phi, -10^3, 10^3},
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 3],
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 2}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[{r Cos[phi], r Sin[phi]}, {r, 0, 10}, {phi, 0, Pi/3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this function was introduced in 1988 and `ParametricRegion` in 2014. This is the function that would traditionally be used for this task, whereas `ParametricRegion` is not just for visualizing but also for doing computations on said regions. A `ParametricRegion` represents an object which we can e.g. use `Area` on.